# How to find which is my default System font?

Tags: macos, font

Of so many fonts installed in /Library/Fonts/ how does OSX - El Capitan determine which font is to be used system wide?

Comment: Used in what context?  For system menus and dialog boxes?

Comment: Yes. Basically, I am on El Capitan and would like to know if the San Francisco font is being used or Helvetica?